# OutputStream delete file contents JAVA

Tags: java, file, objectoutputstream

I have files in who I need to record serialized object. I open `ObjectOutputStream` for writing in files. If I didn't wrote nothing in file, file content get deleted. I don't want content to be deleted when I make `ObjectOutputStream`.

My code (I use Guice),

```
@Provides
@ArticleSerializationOutputStream
public ObjectOutputStream getArticleObjectOutputStream(Config config) {
  ObjectOutputStream out = null;
  String fileName = config.getConfigValue(ARTICLE_SNAPSHOT);
  try {
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    String errorMessage = String.format(IO_EXCEPTION_PROBLEM, fileName);
    addError(errorMessage);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Creating the `ObjectOutputStream` itself won't overwrite anything. I suspect you just created a new `FileOutputStream` which will have truncated any current content unless you tell it to append. I think you want:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
```

to make it append to a file instead of overwriting.

EDIT: Yes, as per your edit, you're creating a new `FileOutputStream` without telling it to append. It's therefore overwriting the file.

Comment: Why is reading the bloody documentation so hard? I don’t get it. :(

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. I use provider instead instancing the OutputStrams in begin with Guice.

```
@Inject @ArticleOutputStream
Provider<OutputStream> articleObjectOutputStream;

articleOutputStream.get();
```

Work fine for now.